# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Jaybizzle\Seasons" not found in "XXXX" Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in "XXXX" on line 4

Tags: php, composer-php

```
  use Jaybizzle\Seasons;
  
  $season = new Seasons;

  echo $season->get();
```

After I enter the site i got that error and I don't know why.

Comment: simply because the class `Jaybizzle\Seasons` was not found, try running `composer install`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?